# Choose a random value between 0.00 and 20.00

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, it is possible to select a random value from a set of 5 options in the following manner:

**Values**

> e.g. 15, 30, 50, 75, or 100

**Formula**

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5),15,30,50,75,100)
```

If I wanted to select a value from a much denser range how would I do it?

> e.g. 0.00, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 ,0.04 ,0.05 ... 19.95, 19.96, 19.97, 19.98, 20.00

What would be the correct formulae?

Comment: `RAND() * 20`, as a first approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following formula:

```
=0.01*RANDBETWEEN(0,2000)
```

This will produce random multiples of **.01**

Answer (score 1):

Scale the output of the random function by multiplying/dividing it by a constant.

For instance, if your Random function outputs floating decimal values between 0 and 1, and you need outputs between 0 and 100, multiply the output of the random function by 100.

If you need the final result to be an integer, you can then round the value to the nearest integer.

It sounds like you want

```
=ROUND(RAND()*20,2)
```

The 20 is the maximum value of your zero-to-maximum range, and the 2 is how many decimal places it'll round the final output to.